# How to extract xyz coordinates from 3D point cloud in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I am using a Kinect for Windows to import 3D images into MATLAB. I want to be able to find the 3D co-ordinates of objects within the 3D scene.

One simple way to do this is to use the `clickA3DPoint` function found [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7594-click3dpoint/content/clickA3DPoint.m), and then click the point I want to know the co-ordinates of.

The problem is `clickA3DPoint` expects the arguments in a `3 by N` matrix, which is the `x` `y` and `z` coordinates of `N` samples. When I use the Kinect to get a point cloud with `depthToPointCloud` it returns a `480 * 640 * 3` matrix.

How can I extract the x, y, and z coordinates from this matrix so I can plot it with `clickA3DPoint`? (or `scatter3`?)

My attempt so far:

```
depthDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',2)  %this is the kinect depth sensor

depthImage = step(depthDevice);  %this takes a depth image. (A 480 * 640 uint16 array)

xyzPoints = depthToPointCloud(depthImage,depthDevice); %convert the depth image to a point cloud

clickA3DPoint(reshape(xyzPoints,[3,307200])) %I'm guessing each of the 480 * 640 points (307200 points) has an x,y and z coordinate, so this concates the coordinates of all these points.
```

But this just plots the points along a diagonal line in the 3D space. How do I actually extract the x, y and z coordinates from a point cloud in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pcshow` function to plot your points, and it will take the M-by-N-by-3 array directly.  You can then turn on [data tips](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html) and click on the points in the plot to see their coordinates.

If you still want to create a 3-by-N matrix, then the easiest way to do that is the following:

```
x = xyzPoints(:,:,1);
y = xyzPoints(:,:,2);
z = zyzPoints(:,:,3);
points3D = [x(:)'; y(:)', z(:)'];
```

Comment: data tips is a life saviour! I've been trying all day to do this. Can't believe its so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Property 'Location' of pointCloud to get the x,y,z.
for example:

```
moving = movingReg.Location;%movingReg is a pointCloud
scatter(moving(:,1),moving(:,2));
```